# when save record it'cause java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Raw Records don't save themselves

Tags: scala, lift, squeryl

User.scala

```
import net.liftweb.record.{ MegaProtoUser, MetaMegaProtoUser }
import net.liftweb.squerylrecord.RecordTypeMode._
import net.liftweb.common._
import net.liftweb.util.FieldError
import net.liftweb.http.S

class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {

  def meta = User

  protected def valUnique(errorMsg: => String)(email: String): List[FieldError] = {
    List[FieldError]()
  }

}

/**
 * The singleton that has methods for accessing the database
 */
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {

  override def basePath = "profile" :: Nil

  override def signupFields = email :: password :: Nil

  override def signupXhtml(user: TheUserType) = {
    (<form method="post" action={ S.uri }><table>
                                            <tr><td colspan="2">{ S.??("sign.up") }</td></tr>
                                            { localForm(user, false, signupFields) }
                                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><user:submit class="btn btn-primary" /></td></tr>
                                          </table></form>)
  }

  override def screenWrap = Full(<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
                                   <lift:bind/>
                                 </lift:surround>)

  // redefine login form for nice formatting
  override def loginXhtml =
    <form method="post" action={ S.uri }>
      <lift:msg show="All"/>
      <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px;">
        <strong>
          { S.??("log.in") }
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left; line-height: 2.5em;margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 20px;">
        { S.??("email.address") }<br/>{ S.??("password") }<br/>
        <a href={ lostPasswordPath.mkString("/", "/", "") }>
          { S.??("recover.password") }
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="line-height: 2.5em;">
        <user:email/>
        <br/>
        <user:password/>
        <br/>
        <user:submit class="btn btn-primary"/>
      </div>
    </form>

  protected def userFromStringId(id: String): Box[User] = from(PPSchema.users)(u =>
    where(u.id === id.toLong)
      select (u)).headOption

  protected def findUserByUserName(email: String): Box[User] = from(PPSchema.users)(u =>
    where(u.email === email)
      select (u)).headOption

  protected def findUserByUniqueId(id: String): Box[User] = userFromStringId(id)
}
```

i got it.add below code in class User.

```
override def saveTheRecord() : Box[User] = {
    val u = User.createRecord.email(email.is).password(password.is).firstName(firstName.is).lastName(lastName.is).validated(validated.is).superUser(superUser.is)

    Full(PPSchema.users.insert(u))
  }
```

error message is below:

Message: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Raw Records don't save themselves
    net.liftweb.record.Record$class.saveTheRecord(Record.scala:89)
    com.posplus.model.User.saveTheRecord(User.scala:17)
    net.liftweb.record.MetaMegaProtoUser$MyUserBridge.save(ProtoUser.scala:294)
    net.liftweb.proto.ProtoUser$class.actionsAfterSignup(ProtoUser.scala:696)
    com.posplus.model.User$.actionsAfterSignup(User.scala:32)
    net.liftweb.proto.ProtoUser$class.testSignup$1(ProtoUser.scala:737)
    net.liftweb.proto.ProtoUser$$anonfun$innerSignup$1$1.apply(ProtoUser.scala:745)
    net.liftweb.proto.ProtoUser$$anonfun$innerSignup$1$1.apply(ProtoUser.scala:745)
    net.liftweb.http.S$NFuncHolder$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(S.scala:190)
    net.liftweb.http.S$NFuncHolder$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(S.scala:190)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:45)
    net.liftweb.http.S$NFuncHolder.apply(S.scala:190)
    net.liftweb.http.S$ProxyFuncHolder.apply(S.scala:115)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$buildFunc$1$2.apply(LiftSession.scala:651)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$16$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(LiftSession.scala:667)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$16$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(LiftSession.scala:667)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:45)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$16.apply(LiftSession.scala:667)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$16.apply(LiftSession.scala:656)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:200)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:200)
    scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:200)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:45)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession.runParams(LiftSession.scala:655)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftSession.processRequest(LiftSession.scala:1074)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.net$liftweb$http$LiftServlet$$dispatchStatefulRequest(LiftServlet.scala:414)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doSession$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:279)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doSession$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:279)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$wrapQuery(S.scala:1376)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_nest2InnerInit$1$$anonfun$apply$34.apply(S.scala:1524)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$doAround(S.scala:1305)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$doAround$1.apply(S.scala:1306)
    org.squeryl.dsl.QueryDsl$class._using(QueryDsl.scala:46)
    org.squeryl.dsl.QueryDsl$class._executeTransactionWithin(QueryDsl.scala:105)
    org.squeryl.dsl.QueryDsl$class.inTransaction(QueryDsl.scala:91)
    net.liftweb.squerylrecord.RecordTypeMode$.inTransaction(RecordTypeMode.scala:34)
    bootstrap.liftweb.Boot$$anon$1.apply(Boot.scala:58)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$doAround(S.scala:1306)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_nest2InnerInit$1.apply(S.scala:1522)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$_nest2InnerInit(S.scala:1521)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39$$anonfun$apply$40$$anonfun$apply$41.apply(S.scala:1561)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$withReq$1.apply(S.scala:1571)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.withReq(S.scala:1570)
    net.liftweb.http.S$.withReq(S.scala:48)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39$$anonfun$apply$40.apply(S.scala:1560)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(S.scala:1559)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit$1$$anonfun$apply$38.apply(S.scala:1558)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit$1.apply(S.scala:1557)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$_innerInit(S.scala:1556)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1$$anonfun$apply$44$$anonfun$apply$45$$anonfun$apply$46$$anonfun$apply$47$$anonfun$apply$48.apply(S.scala:1594)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1$$anonfun$apply$44$$anonfun$apply$45$$anonfun$apply$46$$anonfun$apply$47.apply(S.scala:1592)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:613)
    net.liftweb.http.RequestVarHandler$.apply(Vars.scala:515)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1$$anonfun$apply$44$$anonfun$apply$45$$anonfun$apply$46.apply(S.scala:1591)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:613)
    net.liftweb.http.TransientRequestVarHandler$.apply(Vars.scala:528)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1$$anonfun$apply$44$$anonfun$apply$45.apply(S.scala:1590)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1$$anonfun$apply$44.apply(S.scala:1589)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$S$$_init$1.apply(S.scala:1588)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.net$liftweb$http$S$$*init(S.scala:1587)
    net.liftweb.http.S$class.init(S.scala:1190)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.doSession$1(LiftServlet.scala:278)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.doService(LiftServlet.scala:288)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doIt$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:132)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet$$anonfun$doIt$1$1.apply(LiftServlet.scala:131)
    net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers$class.calcTime(TimeHelpers.scala:344)
    net.liftweb.util.Helpers$.calcTime(Helpers.scala:34)
    net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers$class.logTime(TimeHelpers.scala:363)
    net.liftweb.util.Helpers$.logTime(Helpers.scala:34)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.doIt$1(LiftServlet.scala:131)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet.service(LiftServlet.scala:142)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(HTTPProvider.scala:72)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.URLRewriter$.doWith(Req.scala:1253)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(HTTPProvider.scala:70)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:70)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:70)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply$mcV$sp(HTTPProvider.scala:66)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:60)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$$anonfun$service$2.apply(HTTPProvider.scala:60)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider$class.service(HTTPProvider.scala:60)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter.service(LiftServlet.scala:757)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ServletFilterProvider.scala:67)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:62)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:62)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Vars.scala:619)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Vars.scala:618)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Vars.scala:617)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Vars.scala:616)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:615)
    net.liftweb.http.RequestVarHandler$.apply(Vars.scala:515)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:61)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ServletFilterProvider.scala:61)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Vars.scala:619)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Vars.scala:618)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Vars.scala:617)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Vars.scala:616)
    net.liftweb.util.ThreadGlobal.doWith(ThreadGlobal.scala:71)
    net.liftweb.http.CoreRequestVarHandler$class.apply(Vars.scala:615)
    net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$class.doFilter(ServletFilterProvider.scala:60)
    net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter.doFilter(LiftServlet.scala:757)
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1337)
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.*_doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java)
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:941)
    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that ProtoUser doesn't work with SquerylRecord right now.

Comment: this ProtoUser is in Package net.liftweb.record.would you sure that?last for thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  There are incompatibilities with how Squeryl references primary keys and ProtoUser's fields.  There's beens some talk about work around, but nothing is implemented yet.